# Передача и обработка строк и чисел в JSON

Tags: json, строки, числа, передача-данных

Согласно [стандарту](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-404.pdf) JSON различает числа и строки, передаваемые в качестве параметров.

```css
[
{"property1": 123,
 "property2": '123'}
]
```

Но все-таки JSON - это строка. Есть два вопроса:

1. Как принимающий код обработает эти значения? Как строки или как целое число и строку?
2. Как правильно передавать данные? оставлять так или приводить к одному типу, например, к строковому?

Comment: Строки отличаются кавычками. То, что вы написали это не Json

Comment: В каждом вопросе про JSON, есть человек, который скажет - это не JSON. Что же это? кавычки поправлю

Comment: JSON это строка. Вы же явно хотели написать обычный объект JS

Comment: да, вы правы. я сделал перенос строки для наглядности

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Принимающий код обработает значение как целое число и строку(в данном случае).
2. Оставлять так, как есть. Типы данных в JSON как раз для удобства.

Кстати, у вас в JSON-е ошибка, т.к. нужно писать свойства объектов, а также строки - в двойных кавычках `"`.

Конечно то, как обрабатывается JSON - зависит от используемой библиотеки. Но в 99.99% стандартных библиотек популярных языков - он обрабатывается согласно стандарту.

**Вывод:** хотя JSON и передается как строка, но при парсинге он преобразуется в объекты, массивы, булевы переменные,строки и числа, **в соответствии с типами в конкретном языке программирования** (в ***C***, например, число - примитивный тип, а в ***ruby*** - объект, как и все остальные типы).

**JSON.parse()** в javascript выдаст такой результат(*property1* - число, *property2* - строка):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: спасибо, да кавычки поправлю, код набросал, чтобы донеси мысль.

Comment: еще одно уточнение. если я буду переносить данные из json в БД. например, поле таблицы БД будет ожидать строковый тип, то несмотря на числовой тип значения 123, она переведет его в '123'. значение само подстроится? правильно понимаю?

Comment: @while1pass если у вас есть json-строка, а в БД строковый тип - то в БД запишется та строка, которая была, без всяких ее изменений(именно когда тип строковый!). грубо говоря - БД пофиг что там: строка JSON или коммент под фоткой с котиком:D

Comment: ок, только в вопросе я конкретно привел ситуацию --- "property1": 123, --- допустим, ячейка в бд ожидает СТРОКУ, а ей передают значение выше - ЧИСЛО. будет преобразование в строку как понимаю?

Comment: @while1pass не будет. обновил ответ.

Comment: опять мимо) есть два значения (берем только значения): '123' и 123, при записи в ячейку БД, которая ждет строку. как они запишутся? как '123' и '123'?

Comment: @while1pass видимо я не пойму что вы хотите) ну вот у вас есть в php, js, ruby реальный объект. дальше вы вызываете json_encode() или JSON.stringify() и преобразовуете его(объект) в строку. после этого эта строка ничем не отличается от любой другой строки, и куда вы бы ее не заносили(в бд или передавали по сети или в другую переменную присвоили) - она такой и останется(в формате json). Потом, когда вы решите заново создать из нее объект - вы вызовете json_decode() или JSON.parse() и строка снова станет реальным объектом. надеюсь понял)

Comment: @while1pass `[{"property1": 123, "property2": "123"}]` -  вот такой строка будет после вызова ф-ции сериализации. что бы вы не делали и куда ее не заносили - она МЕНЯТЬСЯ НЕ БУДЕТ.

Comment: тут меня интересует не строка, а ее итерация по компонентам, точнее значения, которые соответствуют ключам (я же их буду вносить в БД). ну, да ладно, проверю на практике, это уже другой вопрос. на основной вы мне отлично объяснили, спасибо вам

Comment: @while1pass если вы имели в виду то, что например будь у вас property1:123, property2:"123" и property3: "test" и вы хотите в БД вносить только значения ключей - то этот вопрос и json не касается)) если там стоит строка(в бд), а вы попытаетесь внести число(1 случай) - то получите или ошибку или преобразование типа в строку, но это уже не json, а работа конкретной бд.

Comment: попробую на практике. поэтому я задался вопросом приведения к одному типу

Comment: @while1pass ок, удачи:D

Answer (score 2):

Люди разрабатывали стандарт JSON, определяли типы для более удобной коммуникации и преобразований между клинтской и серверной сторонами, **а вы хотите все в строку перевести**?

Во многих языках, по умолчанию, при разборе, переданная строка на клиент будет обработана как строка, число, как не удивительно, как число. Если клиентом не определен какой-то либо собственный преобразователь или не используется автоматическое приведение типов.